# DateTimeFormat date validation error

Tags: java, date, gwt, datetime-format

I am trying to validate a date using GWT. For most purposes, using the code below works correctly:

```
boolean valid = true;
    try{
        DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DATE_FORMAT).parseStrict(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        valid = false;
    }
return valid;
```

For example :

10/35/2014 
15/25/2014
104/15/2014
10/500/2014

all return an error.

The problem I am having occurs with this instance:

- 10/20/20144

The DateTimeObject recognizes 20144 as a valid year. However, when I insert this into the SQL datatbase, I receive an error. Is there anyway to alter DateTimeFormat so that this year also throws an error? Or any type of work around??

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

I was able to solve this issue two ways.

1. splitting the original string and checking length of year is only 4 characters
2. creating a date 12/31/3999 and checking that the parsed date is before this date.

Thanks

Comment: You could check the length of your date. Or splitting the string and check the length of the year. Or after parsing the date, checking the year.

Comment: Just thought about checking the year after I parsed it... I am such an idiot -_-

Comment: Mistakes, made they are. #Yoda

Answer (score 1):

20144 is a valid year. It won't happen soon, but it will. The easiest solution in your case is to set a limit on the maximum year that you allow. It can be 9999 (the [maximum year in Microsoft SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)), or something closer depending on your project requirements.